# UIImageView.image is nil in my UITableViewCell when I select cell even though I know it should have a value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, I set the URL for a UIImageView to load an image from. When this image is loaded, I select the cell, and in `didSelectRowWithIndexPath` the cell's image's image is nil. In fact, even labels are nil. All data is nil as though there is no data in the cell, but I could clearly see the cell visually with the data I want in it.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Session.sharedInstance.universities.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("universityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UniversityTableCell

    if (indexPath.row < Session.sharedInstance.universities.count) {

        let university = Session.sharedInstance.universities[indexPath.row]
        cell.setInfo(university.imageUrl)
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("universityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UniversityTableCell

    // This is nil. But why? I set the data in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method
    print(cell.universityImage.image)

}
```

In my UniversityTableCell:

```
class UniversityTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var universityImage: UIImageView!

    func setInfo(url: String) {
        self.universityImage.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: url), usingActivityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.universityImage.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your code to

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UniversityTableCell

     // This is nil. But why? I set the data in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method
      print(cell.universityImage.image)

}
```